# Why can I access the base class aliased types from the derived class?

Tags: c++, templates, language-design

In my development journey, today I found something that I do not understand why happens.

This should represent a generic a base unit in the SI:

```
template<Ratio r, Symbol s>
struct base_unit {
    using ratio = r;
    using symbol = s;
};
```

So, in my public interface, I am able to define a base dimension like this:

```
template <typename Dimension>
struct base_dimension {
    using dimension = Dimension;
};
```

And a concrete base unit like this:

```
struct mass : public base_dimension<mass> {};
```

So, I wanted to design a concept that checks for the presence of those aliases inside a unit, like for example, Kilogram:

```
struct Kilogram: public mass, public base_unit<Kilo, kg> {};
```

So I went ahead, and I wrote this concept, to constrain future implementors:

```
template <typename T>
concept Unit = requires {  
    typename T::base_dimension::dimension;
    typename T::base_unit::ratio;
    typename T::base_unit::symbol;
};
```

But, for my surprise, I am able to write this code:

```
template <typename T>
concept OtherUnitConcept = requires {  
    typename T::dimension;
    typename T::ratio;
    typename T::symbol;
};
```

```
static_assert(Unit<Kilogram>);
static_assert(OtherUnitConcept<Kilogram>);
```

Why I am able to directly request for those alias to `T`? The idea is that I am using those inheritance constructs as `tag dispatching`, and I supposed that I would always should take the full route, `T::base_dimension::dimension` , since `T` doesn't have in it's body definition a `typename dimension`, but `base_dimension` has one, and I looked surprised to be able to directly be able to found `dimension` in the construct `T::dimension`.

[Here's a minimal working example](https://godbolt.org/z/4TcMxWxdG)

Comment: Why wouldn’t you be able? Types that have dimension, ratio and symbol as their inner types will comply to OtherUnit concept. Those inner types don’t have to be the ones from base_xxx.

Comment: [Name lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lookup)

Comment: type alias are also inherited, I don't see any problem here.

Comment: btw the [mcve] is not correct, you can **define** any concept, but they're not checked unless you actually **use** it somewhere.

Comment: @appleapple I am not talking about problems. I am requesting for an explanation of the exposed

Comment: @AlexVergara the point of [mcve] is reproducible **without any change**

Comment: @AlexVergara this is not **minimal** anyway, all those template are unnecessary.

Comment: @AlexVergara I've change the tags [according to your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75802563/accessing-alias-in-inheritance?noredirect=1#comment133716234_75802563)

Comment: the question is not quite clear "Why I am able to directly request for those alias to T? " I mean you can write a concept to request / require anything. I suppose the quesiton is why does some type satify the concept. Which type?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number or in simple terms, why I can access the most inner defined type alias (does not matter if is in a concept or anything)? I mean, why if I have T::base_unit::ratio, I can call directly from T ratio, without base_unit? Or better, why I can use both ways to access that alias

Comment: the thing is that you not do that in code in the question. Its just a concept that can be fullfilled or not, but the question seems to be why some type meets the concept. "Why is `Kilogram` a `Unit`?", right?

Comment: your question reads a bit like "I have `int x= 42;` why can i do `if (x < 100)`.".... I am exaggerting to get the point across. I think I know what you are asking, but its not in the question ("why is `x<100` true")

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number you're right that the code probably won't reflects what I am really asking for. I just wanted to know why a type alias for T::U::X can also be found in the form of T::X, given the types where they are defined. The concept is just the place where I noticed such behaviour, but it could easily be an static assert or another using in another type.

Comment: in the concept you could write `T::foo_whatever;` and the concept would be fine. I suppose what you realized is that `Kilogram` does satisfy the concept, and thats totally missing from the question.

Comment: you ask why does the static assert pass, and that assert should be in the question. The code in the question does not need `T::X` to be accessible.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I always appreciate the conversations with you, but this time I am unable to explain myself better, or to write a better question for what I really want to know. I tried my bests with the last edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TBH, your question should be *Why can I access the base class aliased types from the derived class?*

It's things about qualified name lookup. According to [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/qualified_lookup#Class_members),

> If the lookup of the left hand side name comes up with a class/struct or union name, the name on the right hand side of :: is looked up in the scope of that class (and so may find a declaration of a member of that class or of its base), with the following exceptions

So, `T::dimension` can look up `T::base_dimension::dimension` if `T::dimension` is not found.